# Mysql Using PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I am having a problem getting this php script to run correctly.

Both 'redirect_to()' and '$link' are defined in attached files.

Any tips will be greatly appreciated.

```
if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
$id = $_GET["section"];

$about_me = "../include/about_me.php";

$providers_2 = "../include/2providers.php";

$more_providers = "../include/more_proiders.php";

$section_change = $_POST["section_change"];

$query  = "UPDATE sections SET ":
$query .= "`File Path` = '{$section_change}' ";
$query .= "WHERE id = '{$id}' ";
$query .= "LIMIT 1";
$result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

if ($result && mysqli_affected_rows($link) == 1) {
  // Success
  $_SESSION["message"] = "Section Changed.";
  redirect_to("../index.php?admin=true");
} else {
  // Failure
  echo "System Failure. Please try again later. If problem persists please notify your admin at aqeke.com/powerplaylife-help"
}
}
else {
    print_r( $_POST);

}
```

Comment: How is it not running correctly? Do you get any errors?

Comment: add session_start() to the top of this file right after <?php and see if it changes anything

Comment: Yes, I am getting  a 500 error

Comment: @Rjoel98 what is the error?

Comment: Put `ini_set('display_errors', 'on');` at the beginning of your code

Comment: @JimL [Error] Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 500 (Internal Server Error) (edit_section.php, line 0)

Comment: @VincentDecaux I tried this and it is still failing

Comment: Check your error log file!

Comment: $query  = "UPDATE sections SET ": should be $query  = "UPDATE sections SET ";

Comment: @waterloomatt Thank you for the tip, I totally missed that. Unfortunately it still isn't working.

Comment: you should `ini_set('display_errors', 1); error_reporting(E_ALL);` as mentioned at the beginning of your code, also `redirect_to()` is not a function. where is it defined? What are "attached files"? Where are you including them? The code you show does **not** include any files. You would have to use `require_once "../include/2providers.php";`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this.

You had

1. : instead of ;
2. <strike>an extra curly brace</strike>. You were missing a semi-colon at the end of the "System Failure" line.

In future, you can use a formatting tool which will help you quickly diagnose the issue - http://beta.phpformatter.com/

```
<?php


if (isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    $id = $_GET["section"];

    $about_me = "../include/about_me.php";

    $providers_2 = "../include/2providers.php";

    $more_providers = "../include/more_proiders.php";

    $section_change = $_POST["section_change"];

    $query = "UPDATE sections SET ";
    $query .= "`File Path` = '{$section_change}' ";
    $query .= "WHERE id = '{$id}' ";
    $query .= "LIMIT 1";
    $result = mysqli_query($link, $query);

    if ($result && mysqli_affected_rows($link) == 1) {
        // Success
        $_SESSION["message"] = "Section Changed.";
        redirect_to("../index.php?admin=true");
    } else {
        // Failure
        echo "System Failure. Please try again later. If problem persists please notify your admin at aqeke.com/powerplaylife-help";
    }
} else {
    print_r($_POST);

}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

In this code:

```
if ($result && mysqli_affected_rows($link) == 1) {
  // Success
   $_SESSION["message"] = "Section Changed.";
  redirect_to("../index.php?admin=true");
} else {
  // Failure
   echo "System Failure. Please try again later. If problem persists please 
notify your admin at aqeke.com/powerplaylife-help"
}
else {
   print_r( $_POST);
}
```

You have an `else` block followed immediately by another `else` block. That's invalid, and causes an error. Try re-checking your code, specially the placement of closing brackets.

Comment: Made some corrections to the else statements above, but it still isn't running

Comment: What error are you getting now?